# reading java jar command console output

Tags: java, command-line, scripting

I am running a command line program as follows:

```
java -jar myjar.jar -host localhost MonkeyProject/BAT_Login_Online_V1.mt
```

Which prints the following output:

> result: OK

I am running the above command in a loop and want to read the output printed on the console in my script to make some decisions.

So how do i read it in the script?

Comment: with a pipe. What OS are you using?

Comment: Something like `java -jar myjar.jar ... | myscript` should work. Is that what you're asking? Is your script already written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using *nix:

```
var=`java -jar myjar.jar`
```

The output of the java program will be stored in `var`

If using Batch, you can do it by outputting into a file, then reading it back into a variable like this:

```
java -jar myjar.jar > file.txt
set /p var=<file.txt
```